# Opencart 1.5.2 Show Category's In One Drop Down

Tags: php, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, opencart

I want to show all the category's in one drop down. Currently it shows each category in as its own drop down, I want one master drop down link then all the category's listed in that drop down and all there children.

categories
 - cat 1
 - cat 2
 - cat 3 --- cat 3 child 1
 - cat 4   - cat 3 child 2
 - cat 5   - cat 3 child 3
 - cat 6
 - cat 7

Answer (score 1):

This is motly just about the HTML+CSS and JS - simply enclose the present categories HTML markup into one new UL - so from

```
<ul>
    <li>Cat 1</li>
    <li>Cat 2
        <ul>
            <li>Cat 2 child 1</li>
        </ul>
<ul>
```

You will get

```
<ul>
    <li>Categories
        <ul>
            <li>Cat 1</li>
            <li>Cat 2
                <ul>
                    <li>Cat 2 child 1</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        <ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now only a few modifiactions of JS and CSS should be enough.
Of course the categories are written down by PHP so just encapsulate the present markup into one new UL-LI.

I cannot give You the whole code example and JS script cos I take money for implementing and programming OpenCart eshop solutions :-).